# Accessing a class from another class?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

[image: my work]

(pic above)
I am trying to access the Food.calories or Food.carbs from the Fram1.java but it is not letting me. Can someone tell me why?

Detailed info...I am trying to practice Java by programming a calorie counter, and the Frame1 is a GUI class. I am trying to write another class to put all the food items along with their amount of carbs...etc as their attributes. Answering the first question will be enough, but any tips of other ways of doing it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Dont post pictures, post the full code here.

Comment: We can't see your other code, how are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't enough context information to answer it. Also, you're not allowed to post images of code here, post it as text.

Comment: There is no "Food.calories", there is "Food.cals." And what do you mean "wont' let you?" If you wish to program, the first thing you must learn is to *be specific* and *accurate*.

Comment: @WilomGfx *post the full code here* - Not full, only relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *calories* is not a field within the Food class.

Secondly, you are treating the *carbs* field as if it were **static**.

- **static** variables are owned by the class.
- Non-static variables are owned by the class instances.

---

You could make the fields in the Food class **static** as follows:

`public static int cals, carbs, fat, protein;`

However, if you needed multiple food items within your system, you would need to create instances of the food class. Also, it might help if your constructor had parameters for setting the fields rather than every food item having 10 of each trait.

Regardless, here is an example of instantiation:

```
public class Frame1
{
    private Food genericFood;

    public Frame1() 
    {
        genericFood = new Food(); 
        System.out.println(genericFood.cals);
    }
}
```

Because you are creating an instance of the Food class, you would not need the **static** typing.

Furthermore, I recommend looking into *encapsulation*.